# RemoteMediaClient setStreamVolume doesn't changing cast volume

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Through CastSession I'm getting an instance of RemoteMediaClient to send events to receiver.

```
mCastSession.getRemoteMediaClient().play();

mCastSession.getRemoteMediaClient().pause();

mCastSession.getRemoteMediaClient().seek(position * 1000);
```

All above calls works fine, but `mCastSession.getRemoteMediaClient().setStreamVolume(1.0);` doesn't change the volume. On my other implementation using SDK 2.0 works fine, but now with SDK 3.0 it does nothing. Is that a bug or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not use stream volume, instead use the system volume: `mCastSession.setVolume(level)`.