# Google Cast SDK RemoteMediaClient setStreamVolume not changing volume of cast on iOS

Tags: ios, google-cast-sdk

I am having the exact same issue as described [in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498516/remotemediaclient-setstreamvolume-doesnt-changing-cast-volume), though it seems that on iOS there is no setVolume function in RemoteMediaClient.

For reference, here is what my setStreamVolume call looks like:

```
if let request = sessionManager.currentCastSession?.remoteMediaClient?.setStreamVolume(volume) {
        request.delegate = self
    }
```

In addition, other calls work just fine such as

```
if let request = sessionManager.currentCastSession?.remoteMediaClient?.pause() {
        request.delegate = self
    }
```

Does iOS have another function I need to call so set the volume, or is my implementation incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution. Make an instance of GCKUIDeviceVolumeController then when you call setVolume, it changes the volume of the current cast session.

```
private let volumeController = GCKUIDeviceVolumeController()    
volumeController.setVolume(volume)
```